# "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" when trying to add a cookie to a variable?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting an error on line 31 of this [script](https://znepb.me/games/money-clicker/game/game.js):

```
var cAdd = 1;

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var myCookie = getCookie("money");

if (myCookie == null) {
    document.cookie = "money="+money;
}


console.log(Number(getCookie("money")))
document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = "$"+getCookie("money");

var giveMoney = (function() {
    return function() {
        console.log(Number(getCookie("money"))
        console.log(Number(getCookie("money")) += cAdd)
        var addMoney = Number(getCookie("money")) += cAdd;
        document.cookie = "money=" + addMoney;
        document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = "$"+getCookie("money");

        return getCookie("money");
    }
}(0)); // -1 if you want the first increment to return 0

var removeCookieNotice = (function() {
    return function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('CookieNotice');
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        return false;
    }
}());
```

I've tried googling the error, but to no peril.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Which line is that? What exactly is the error message?

Comment: It looks like line 31 is this one: `console.log(Number(getCookie("money")) += cAdd)`. I'm really not sure what you're trying to do on that line, but you're trying to assign to `Number(getCookie("money"))` (since `+=` adds and then assigns the result back into the same variable) - and this raises the error since that expression isn't a variable or property name, so you can't assign to it.

Comment: If you want to try it, the website is https://znepb.me/games/money-clicker/game/game.html

Comment: I think I figured it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is corrected version, you had an error on line 33:
`var addMoney = Number(getCookie("money")) += cAdd;`
Basically you already have assignment "=" sign on the left, and then trying to += on the right end of the line.

```
var cAdd = 1;

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var myCookie = getCookie("money");

if (myCookie == null) {
    document.cookie = "money="+money;
}


console.log(Number(getCookie("money")))
document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = "$"+getCookie("money");

var giveMoney = (function() {
    return function() {
        console.log(Number(getCookie("money"))
        console.log(Number(getCookie("money")) += cAdd)
        // You don't need += here, + is just enaugh
        var addMoney = Number(getCookie("money")) + cAdd;
        document.cookie = "money=" + addMoney;
        document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = "$"+getCookie("money");

        return getCookie("money");
    }
}(0)); // -1 if you want the first increment to return 0

var removeCookieNotice = (function() {
    return function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('CookieNotice');
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        return false;
    }
}());
```

Comment: It seems to be removing everything from the HTML file except for the money div element.

Comment: Well If you provide an working example I could check what is wrong, but this way I really can tell why is not working. This was the cause for the “Invalid left-hand side in assignment” error .. you might have some logical error aside that, not sure.

Comment: Now it isn't updating the money header and and I'm getting the error:

`
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at game.js:33
    at <anonymous>:1:1
`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null -> this means that your getElementById is not finding the right node, did you check you have an <div id="m"> ?

Comment: I changed it to `moneyElement`, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: Is it because it is running from an imported script?

Comment: As I said earlier, its impossible to figure out what's happening without an working example. What do you mean by imported script ?

Comment: The `<link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">` in the HTML file.

Comment: That has nothing to do with any of the problems

Answer (score 0):

If its this line:
    `console.log(Number(getCookie("money")) += cAdd)`

You don't want the `=`, you're trying to assign add number value to a function. Just have the `+` not `+=`.